# Need guidance in understanding the reason of my ML model's failure

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am a beginner in ML and thus was watching a video for my project on intro to huggingface and sentiment analysis and followed each step side by side/
But the prediction i am getting is not expected though my model has a good accuracy
[image]

Yet my prediction expectation is not matching as it fails in simple words

[image]
any insights would be aprreciated.

I am new to this field and am completely clueless like why did it happen for so simple words too

Comment: Dear heckr, there is not much we can help you with as you need to provide much more information on what you actually did and what might have gone wrong in the code specifically. Otherwise it's equivalent of asking "why did my food taste bad yesterday?". No way to answer that without more to go on. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to formulate a question that can be answered. It is also better to show code and only in very rare cases it makes sense to use images (especially not useful are images of copyable-text ;D).

Comment: On a second note: Why do you think it fails on this one example? It clearly has "joy" as the single most likely answer for your emotion in the predicted image. To me it seems like you confuse the overall "accuracy" of 92% with the output of ~60% for "joy" here (which is not the accuracy). Those two numbers are not the same! Have you tried predicting the most likely emotion for each image in your whole test-set (and not only one image) and see what the number of correct predictions are? It might turn out to be this 92% if you divide it by the number of samples in the test set.

Comment: @Baradrist Ohk..so for context : I am using the dataset : emotions (https://huggingface.co/datasets/dair-ai/emotion) and the model i am using is fine-tuned version of distilbert-base-uncased (https://huggingface.co/dcssdc/finetuning-emotion-model?text=embarassing).

Comment: @Baradrist Actually what I meant was that when I tried to predict the emotions in my statement "it is an embarassing product"..it showed a high percentage of "joy"..thats what I am confused about

Comment: So, this is one example. Back to what I wrote before: Does it fail for many more (how is it on the whole test set)? Or is it just one that is inside the ~8% cases that just fail.